# How to identify the iframe using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

HTML:

```
<iframe allowpaymentrequest="true" allowtransparency="true" src="https://shopify.wintopay.com/
cd_frame_id_="ca9e4ad6a1559de159faff5c1f563d59"
name="WinCCPay"
id="win-cc-pay-frame"
```

I'm trying to input text in a CC field. Apparently its in an iframe I picked the last one in the HTML and tried to select it from the identifiers above but I keep getting the element couldn't be found

```
iframe= wd.find_element_by_id("win-cc-pay-frame")    

wd.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

The frame is currently being shown in the browser so no need for implicit wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify the [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#win-cc-pay-frame[name='WinCCPay'][src^='https://shopify.wintopay.com']")))
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='win-cc-pay-frame' and @name='WinCCPay'][starts-with(@src, 'https://shopify.wintopay.com')]")))
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Im trying that right now still not working

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: it worked thank you I was running it in a separate cell after it was already selected so it was reading undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be that the name and id of the element are dynamic and change for each unique checkout window? Can you check if adding `class` attribute at iframe tag and find element by this attribute?

It must be similar to:

```
iframe = wd.find_element_by_class_name('card-pay-iframe')
wd.switch_to.frame(iframe)
...
wd.switch_to.default_content()
```

good coding! ¯_(ツ)_/¯